# Detect deletion of file when previewed in lightning

Tags: lightning, chatter-file

[image: ***enter image description here***]

How to detect Delete button press in the file opened in preview lightning community using e.lightning:openFiles event and perform some controller action.

[image]

Comment: What controller action you want to perfrom? Cant that be done in Trigger?

Comment: I need the Id of the document that is deleted and store it in an attribute.

Comment: I think you can write onDelete trigger on ContentDocumentLink and store that documentId anywhere.

Comment: Do we have any events in lightning that can detect.?

Comment: There isnt seem to be an event for this, so I think thats not possible . WOuld love to be wrong though. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:openFiles/documentation4